# How to efficiently use factors in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I want to use factors, but ran into some problems. My questions might reveal that I didn't understand factors entirely :)

Consider the following data "my_data" for example (the real data is much bigger, but of similar form):

```
0,stack
0,exchange
0,overflow
1,list
1,stack
```

The first column is the *user_id* the second column are *tags* used by the user. I want to compute tag intersections of all users. To do this efficiently I'd like to compute them on integers and not on strings.

So I though factors are the way to go. Making a factor out of column 2 gives me one which looks like this:

```
Factor w/ levels "stack", "exchange", "overflow", "list": 1 2 3 4 1
```

Next thing I do is:

```
unique(my_data[my_data$V1 == 0, 2])
```

To get all tags for the user with id 0 which of course returns a vector with strings. How do I now get the corresponding indices from the factor for this vector?

Comment: `as.numeric(unique(my_data[my_data$V1 == 0, 2]))`?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Efficiency-wise it shouldn’t make a difference whether you use factors or strings: as far as I know, newer versions of R perform string pooling on strings in a vector/data.frame, so that comparisons are effectively just a pointer comparison, same as comparing integers.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm going to try it without using factors. I'm still a bit curious how to get (1, 2, 3) instead of (stack, exchange, overflow). @Roland s answer could be right, but the as.numeric obviously doesn't know which factor to use to convert.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". If you've got 1MM+ rows of data and are doing this operation very frequently, that would seem like a good time to worry about doing it efficiently. Otherwise just do it naturally.

Comment: Like the cite :) but I'm working with 14MM rows with an old laptop. So optimization is a thing here. Nevertheless I like to really figure out how factors are used.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the data.table package!

```
test <- data.table(id = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), tag = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'))

## Sort IDs by tag 
test[,id, by = tag]

## Return True for tags used by ID == 0, False otherwise
test[,id==0, by = tag]

## Return tags used by ID == 0
test[id ==0,id, by = tag]
test[id ==0,tag]

## Return tags used by all IDs
n.ids<-length(unique(test$id))
test[length(unique(id==n.ids)),tag]
```

Hope that helps!